# Truncate string in Laravel blade templates

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, template-engine, texttrimming

Is there a truncate modifier for the blade templates in Laravel, pretty much like Smarty?

I know I could just write out the actual php in the template but i'm looking for something a little nicer to write (let's not get into the whole PHP is a templating engine debate).

So for example i'm looking for something like:

```
{{ $myVariable|truncate:"10":"..." }}
```

I know I could use something like Twig via composer but I'm hoping for built in functionality in Laravel itself.

If not is it possible to create your own reusable modifiers like Smarty provides. I like the fact that Blade doesn’t overkill with all the syntax but I think truncate is a real handy function to have.

I'm using Laravel 4.

Comment: what about laravel  5 ?

Comment: @HosMercury For L5 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281013/how-to-use-illuminate-support-strslug-in-my-laravel-5-app

Comment: I hope and pray that you are not working on laravel 4 anymore. :D

Comment: @Vipertecpro hehe, wouldn't that be something! Laravel has come a long way since.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> **Update for Laravel 7.***: [Fluent Strings](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#fluent-strings) i.e a more fluent, object-oriented interface for working with string values, allowing you to chain multiple string operations together using a more readable syntax compared to traditional string operations.

[limit](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-fluent-str-limit) Example :

```
$truncated = Str::of('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')->limit(20);
```

**Output**

```
The quick brown fox...
```

[words](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-fluent-str-words) Example :

```
$string = Str::of('Perfectly balanced, as all things should be.')->words(3, ' >>>');
```

**Output**

```
Perfectly balanced, as >>>
```

> **Update for Laravel 6.*** : You require this package to work all laravel
> helpers `composer require laravel/helpers`

For using helper in controller, don't forget to include/use class as well

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

> **Laravel 5.8 Update**

This is for handling **characters from the string** :

```
{!! Str::limit('Lorem ipsum dolor', 10, ' ...') !!}
```

**Output**

```
Lorem ipsu ...
```

This is for handling **words from the string** :

```
{!! Str::words('Lorem ipsum dolor', 2, ' ...') !!}
```

**Output**

```
Lorem ipsum ...
```

Here is the latest helper documentation for handling string [Laravel Helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#available-methods)

Comment: very clean solution. worked for me. best answer IMO

Comment: @maximus1127 Thank you so much for your efforts towards learning, I'm glad I can be useful for you.

Comment: Great! Kind of answer i'd love to see more.

Comment: What will happen it you have string like Lorem ipsum's  dolor will it return correct result ?

Comment: @Rishi Yes it will return the correct result, btw which method are you talking about limit ? or words ?

Answer (score 250):

In Laravel 4 & 5 (up to 5.7), you can use `str_limit`, which limits the number of characters in a string.

While in Laravel 5.8 up, you can use the `Str::limit` helper.

```
//For Laravel 4 to Laravel 5.5
{{ str_limit($string, $limit = 150, $end = '...') }}
//For Laravel 5.5 upwards
{{ \Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($string, 150, $end='...') }}
```

For more Laravel helper functions http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#strings

Comment: Correct answer since use case is in Blade view.

Comment: In version 5.8 `str` helpers got removed you must use `Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($string)` instead

Comment: str_limit is deprecated

Comment: First 3 characters: {{ \Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($string, 0, 3) }}

Comment: new  helper added str($string)->limit(150, $end) laravel 6+

Answer (score 44):

Laravel 4 has `Str::limit` which will truncate to the exact number of characters, and also `Str::words` which will truncate on word boundary.

Check out:

- http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Support/Str.html#method_limit

Comment: Do you know if an equivalent of `Str::words` exist in Larvel 5.2 ?

Comment: No. Looks like it limits number of words now, not characters. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php#L182

Comment: That was what I was looking for ! Thx !

Answer (score 38):

**Edit: This answer is was posted during the Laravel 4 beta, when Str class did not exist. There is now a better way to do it in Laravel 4 - which is Dustin's answer below. I cannot delete this answer due to SO rules (it wont let me)**

Blade itself does not have that functionality.

In Laravel 3 there was the Str class - which you could do:

```
{{ Str::limit($myVariable, 10) }}
```

At this stage I do not believe the Str class is in Laravel 4 - [but here is a port of it that you can include in composer](https://github.com/meido/str) to add to your own project

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, seems I will have to cave in and use the Meido ports lol

Comment: Nowadays Laravel 4 has the Str class. See Dustin Graham's response.

Comment: Yes - that is correct. When I originally posted this answer it was during Laravel 4 Beta, when the Str class did not exist

Comment: Where is the origianl answer? Its freaking impossible to find any docs for 4.1 now... :(

Answer (score 11):

To keep your code DRY, and if your content comes from your model you should adopt a slightly different approach. Edit your model like so (tested in L5.8):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function getShortDescriptionAttribute()
    {
        return Str::words($this->description, 10, '...');
    }
}
?>
```

Then in your view :

```
{{ $comment->short_description }}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can Set the namespace like:

```
{!! \Illuminate\Support\Str::words($item->description, 10,'....')  !!}
```

Answer (score 4):

For simple things like this I would prefer to make a helper - for example:

create a `helpers.php` file in your `/app/helpers.php` with following content:

```
<?php
if (! function_exists('short_string')) {
    function short_string($str) {
            $rest = substr($str, 0, 10);
            return $rest;
    }
}
```

Register the `helper.php` at autoload in your `composer.json`

```
   "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    }
```

After that you can use in your blade file for example:

```
{{ short_string($whatever_as_text) }}
```

You can use this simple function, then, globally in your app.

Answer (score 2):

This works on Laravel 5:

```
{!!strlen($post->content) > 200 ? substr($post->content,0,200) : $post->content!!}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set string limit as below example:

```
<td>{{str_limit($biodata ->description, $limit = 20, $end = '...')}}</td>
```

It will display only the 20 letters including whitespaces and ends with ....

Example image[image: It shows the example of string limit]

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 4 & 5 (up to 5.7), you can use str_limit, which limits the number of characters in a string.

While in Laravel 7 up, you can use the Str::limit helper.

```
//For Laravel  to Laravel 7

{{ Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($post->title, 20, $end='...') }}
```

Comment: Laravel 7, use only

{{ Str::limit($chamado->subClient->name, 10) }}

Answer (score 1):

You can use sub_str:

```
{{substr($myVariable,10)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Str::words method limits the number of words in a string. An additional string may be passed to this method via its third argument to specify which string should be appended to the end of the truncated string:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return Str::words('Perfectly balanced, as all things should be.', 3, ' >>>');

// Perfectly balanced, as >>>
```

You may pass a third argument to the method to change the string that will be appended to the end of the truncated string:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$truncated = Str::limit('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 20, ' (...)');

// The quick brown fox (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 6 Update:

```
@php
$value = 'Artificial Intelligence';
$var = Str::limit($value, $limit = 15, $end = '');
print_r($var);
@endphp

<p class="card-text">{{ Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($value, 7) }}</p>
<h2 class="main-head">{!! Str::limit($value, 5) !!}</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example below, work with laravel 8.

`{!! Str::words("$post->content", 8, ' ...') !!}`

`{!! Str::limit("$post->content", 15, ' ...') !!}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Laravel Blade directive like this.

```
Str::limit('$yourString',numberOfElement).
```

For example Str::limit('Test', 3) will show you Tes...