# How to use Illuminate\Support\Str::slug in my Laravel 5 app?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm doing the following in the

```
public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
{
    parent::boot($events);

    // set Tag slug
    Tag::saving(function($tag)
    {
        //slugify name
        $tag->slug = Str::slug($tag->name);
    });
}
```

When I run it in tinker, I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Providers\Str' not found in /var/www/questions-l5/app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php on line 35
```

..but I don't know the Laravel way to import it. Do I need to just use `use`, I tried to add the following to the config/app.php file:

```
'aliases' => [
...
'Str'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Str',
```

.. didn't seem to make much difference though.

http://chrishayes.ca/blog/code/laravel-4-generating-unique-slugs-elegantly
http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Support/Str.html

Comment: `str_slug($title, $separator);` didn't work for you ?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I don't think you need to create alias here, so just add

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

to your model.

Comment: or better yet you can add the facade and just add `use Str;` at the top of your file where you will use it.

Comment: Limonte, how can I use Str in blade files? `{{ use Illuminate\Support\Str; }}` gives error.

Comment: str_slug is deprecated in Laravel 5.8, being removed in 5.9. 

In controllers, models, you can just add:

`use Illuminate\Support\Str;`

In a blade/view, you can do 

`{{ \Illuminate\Support\Str::slug($title) }}`

Comment: The facade is loaded by default, so you can just use `Str::slug($title)` in blade files

Answer (score 11):

Edit: As samiles pointed out, `str_slug($text)` has been removed in Laravel 6.0.

In Laravel 5 you can use `str_slug($text)` directly. You no longer have to use the Facade.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-str-slug

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is [deprecated in Laravel 5.8.](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-8-deprecates-string-and-array-helpers)

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same issue. Adding the line to aliases in the `app\config\app.php` file is the correct way to fix this.

```
'alias' => [
     ...
     'Str' => Illuminate\Support\Str::class,
     ...
],
```

Doing it this way avoids:

1. the need to add a `use Illuminate\Support\Str;` line in your blade file
2. the need to fully quality the class, i.e `\Illuminate\Support\Str::slug($tag->name)`

In fact you can see that Mr. Otwell includes this line in [Laravel 5.8](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.8.0/config/app.php).

I'm not sure why this didn't work for you. It could be that your Laravel is out of date. Make sure you've upgraded to 5.8 and then run `composer update`.

Answer (score 1):

you can call it by \Str::slug();
you dont have to register an alias to make it works, the Str class is not a facades, but a real static class

Answer (score 0):

In laravel version 5.4, write like

```
Str::slug()
```

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5 is simpler, you can use these helpers:

Before Laravel 5.8 (from this version is deprecated):

```
str_slug($tag->name);
```

After Laravel 5.4:

```
Str::slug($tag->name)
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is [deprecated in Laravel 5.8.](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-8-deprecates-string-and-array-helpers)