# class Str not is missing but i dont know how to define it

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

> Class 'Str' not found (View:
>   C:\wamp\www\laravel\example\resources\views\pages\index.blade.php)

I have also tried

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

& use Str;

Comment: could you also show what code have you written in your blade file ?

Comment: In your index.blade, try `{{ \Illuminate\Support\Str::function() }}`

Comment: <td>{{Str::limit($page->description, 100)}}</td>

Comment: Can you try <td>{{ \Str::limit($page->description, 100) }}</td> In your index blade.

Comment: which version of laravel you are using, for 5.8 taylor has removed string and array classed from laravel

Comment: @umefarooq laravel version 2.0 & laravel framework version 5.7

Comment: @ArtisanBay sorry sir but same error.

Comment: for what you are using Str Class? are you calling any method if method use string helpers

Comment: @umefarooq for limiting the description  in  my adminpanel

Comment: Where did you try the `use Illuminate\Support\Str;`? It needs to be at the beggining of the file in a php block.

Comment: Could you try to debug the string inside of your Controller method like: 
$truncated = Illuminate\Support\Str::limit('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 20); dd($truncated);
See if you can dump the result there.

Comment: @apokryfos i`m defining it in my controller,can u please tell me where and how to use it.

Comment: You need to use it in the same file you are using `Str`. `use` only counts for the file you declare it in.

Comment: @ArtisanBay i`m new in laravel and dont know how to use debug in VSCode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Illuminate\Support\Str::slug in my Laravel 5 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281013/how-to-use-illuminate-support-strslug-in-my-laravel-5-app)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class yourController extends Controller
{
   public method yourMethod() {

       $truncated = Illuminate\Support\Str::limit('The quick brown fox', 5); 
       dd($truncated);

   }
}
```

OR

You can also use Str like below also:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class yourController extends Controller
{
   public method yourMethod() {

       $truncated = Str::limit('The quick brown fox', 5); 
       dd($truncated);

   }
}
```

You can debug like above inside your controller file

Inside your **blade** file you use the Str helper function like below:

```
<td>{{ Illuminate\Support\Str::limit('The quick brown fox', 5) }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the Laravel Str class, you may add a line to the 'aliases' section into the config/app.php file

```
    'Str' => Illuminate\Support\Str::class,
```

then run

```
    composer dump-autoload
```

Restart the server.

Comment: That's nice, but how do you use the alias?

Answer (score 0):

I've used:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

in my Controller and

```
<td>{{ Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($page->description, 35)}}</td>
```

in my page where I wanted to use limit.