# Laravel Limit Characters - PHP

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I used this line of code to show next post title on my app

```
<span class="blog-title-next"> {{ $post->nextPost()['title'] }} </span>
```

How can I limit the title name to show only first 10 characters?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012712/truncate-string-in-laravel-blade-templates

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could use the [`str_limit()`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-str-limit) helper function:

```
{{ str_limit($post->nextPost()['title'], 10) }}
```

For newer version of laravel

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$truncated = Str::limit('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 20, ' (...)');

// The quick brown fox (...)
```

Comment: you can do {{ str_limit($post->nextPost(), $limit = 150, $end = '...') }}

Comment: you guys are timesaver.. (y)