# How to display only a part of a string in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, string, laravel-5

I have a description field with more than 100 words,but I need to show only 10 characters on my blade. How can I do this?

Comment: Please describe you question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncate string in Laravel blade templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012712/truncate-string-in-laravel-blade-templates)

Comment: This helps, http://stackoverflow.com/a/24902688/6521116

Comment: I've a string of length more than 100 characters. But  only first 10 characters are  needed to be display in my blade in laravel 5.2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use str_limit, refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24902688/6521116)

```
{{ str_limit($string, $limit = 10, $end = '...') }}
```

Comment: Thanks..This is help full. But can u mention the fields inside the ()

Comment: str_limit is deprecated in PHP 7

Answer (score 10):

You can show a part (first 10 characters) of a string using

```
{{substr($myStr, 0, 10)}}
```

in laravel blade template.

Comment: This was very help full dear.

Comment: @HelenaHannahG Glad to help you.. If you need further assistance.. I would love to help.

Comment: @ Shakti Phartiyal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 9.x.x

If you want to show only the first character of the string, then:

```
{{substr($str, 0, 1)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Str helper for Laravel.

```
$converted = Str::substr('The Laravel Framework', 4, 7);
```

return 'Laravel'